# AWS SQS possible to poll for more than 20 seconds from the console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am a bit confused.
I've seen the max polling duration for a queue is 20 seconds.
However if I try to poll a queue from the AWS console with "Send and receive messages" feature,
I can edit the "poll duration" and the value can be between 1 and 999 ...
Any explanation why ?

Comment: Because the UI can poll repeatedly!?

Comment: Are you talking about the features in the SQS management console? It would be continually looping and calling the same API that you can call. You can implement the same functionality yourself, by calling the API again when it returns zero messages.